# Best practice for initial return in a REST-like image upload api endpoint?

Tags: api, http, https, upload, image-uploading

When sending a file, e.g. an image, over HTTP to an API, how should the server respond?

Examples:

- respond as soon as file is written to disk
- respond only when file is written, processed, checksummed, thumbnailed, watermarked etc.
- respond as fast as possible with a link to the resource (even if it's a 404 for a few moments afterwards)
- add a 'task' endpoint and respond instantly with a task ID to track the progress before data transfer & processing (eventually including path to resource)

**Edit**: Added one idea from an answer to a similar question: [rest api design and workflow to upload images.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285047/rest-api-design-and-workflow-to-upload-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client doesn't know about disks, processing, checksumming, thumbnailing, etc.

The options then are pretty simple. You either want to return the HTTP request as quickly as possible, or you want the client to wait until you *know* the operation was successful.

If you want the client to wait, return `201 Created`. If you want to return as quickly as possible, return `202 Accepted`.

Both are acceptable designs. You should let your own requirements dictate which is better for your case. I would say that by default it's a good idea to 'default' to waiting until the HTTP request was guaranteed to be successful, and only use `202 Accepted` if that was a specific requirement.

You *could* also let the client decide with a `Prefer` header:

```
Prefer: respond-async, wait=100
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#section-4.3